# Plotly.js Click event

Tags: javascript, onclick, html, plotly

I'm using Plotly writing a webpage. The problem is that when I'm using the `Plotly_onclick` event, there seems to be something wrong.
Specifically, when I click using my mouse, it doesn't react. When I click using the touchpad of my laptop, i.e. I push the touchpad, it doesn't react either. Only when I heavily touch my touchpad, it reacts.
I cannot handle this. Is there anyone know how to fix it?

The code for click event is here:

```
.on('plotly_click', function (event, eventdata) {

        var point = eventdata.points[0];

        var traceColor = point.fullData.marker.color,
            newAnnotation = {
                x: point.xaxis.d2l(point.x),
                y: point.yaxis.d2l(point.y),
                ax: 0,
                ay: -50,
                arrowhead: 6,
                bgcolor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.75)',
                arrowcolor: traceColor,
                font: {color: traceColor},
                text: point.data.name + ':' + point.y + 'on ' + point.x
            },
            newIndex = (rangePlot.layout.annotations || []).length;
            console.log(newIndex);

        var TextFromUser = {name: point.data.name, time: point.x, value: point.y};

        if(TextFromUser['time'].length==10)
        {
            TextFromUser['time']=TextFromUser['time']+' 00:00';
        }
        else if(TextFromUser['time'].length==13)
        {
            TextFromUser['time']=TextFromUser['time']+':00';
        }
        else;



        if (newIndex) {

            var foundCopy = false;
            rangePlot.layout.annotations.forEach(function (ann, sameIndex) {
                if (ann.text === newAnnotation.text) {
                    Plotly.relayout(rangePlot, 'annotations[' + sameIndex + ']', 'remove');
                    foundCopy = true;
                }
            });
            if (foundCopy) return;
        }

        Plotly.relayout(rangePlot, 'annotations[' + newIndex + ']', newAnnotation);

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

example ref:
https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/

code:

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
    var pts = '';
    for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
        pts = 'x = '+data.points[i].x +'\ny = '+
            data.points[i].y.toPrecision(4) + '\n\n';
    }
    alert('Closest point clicked:\n\n'+pts);
});
```

It has some lagoons but it's a start for the events to fire...